# Autoboxing. values not changed

Tags: java

```
public class Autoboxing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int x=10;
    Integer oldValue=x;
    change(oldValue);
    System.out.println("value:"+oldValue);
}
static void change(Integer value){
    value=100;
}
```

}

Hi, I am trying to autobox a int value into Integer type.
Then pass the Integer object to a method to change the number .
But the number doesnt change. it still prints out 10? 
Could some one spot my error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is pass-by-value not by reference, that means that, after calling method `change` value of `oldValue` would not be affected with modifications that you've done in the called method.

Comment: static int change(int value){
    value=100;
    return 100;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
     int x=10;
    Integer oldValue=x;
    int z = change(oldValue);
    System.out.println("value:"+z);
    } this will give you 100

Answer (score 1):

**Wrappers of primitive types are immodifiables.**

It means that you **can't change the content of an Integer**, but only reassign it.

You will have the same behaviour with any immodifiable class. As an example with `String`.